# Trying to make example work: How to use ASP.NET AJAX UpdatePanel in ModalPopup?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-4.0

I found this article that could help me with an issue I'm currently having. The problem is that I'm having a hard time trying to make it work. The article is [How to use ASP.NET AJAX UpdatePanel in ModalPopup](http://www.jamestsai.net/Blog/post/How-to-use-ASPNET-AJAX-UpdatePanel-in-ModalPopup.aspx)

So I created an even simpler example, but the issue is that `Label lblText` is not being updated (it remains with *this is the label*), even though the codebehind is being executed since it hits a breakpoint. So any help is appreciated.

So here's the markup:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server"> 
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"> 
</asp:ScriptManager> 
<div> 
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpOutterUpdatePanel" runat="server"> 
         <ContentTemplate> 
            <div id="divControlContainer" runat="server">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnRed" runat="server"  onclick="lbtnRed_Click">Red</asp:LinkButton>
             </div> 
            <input id="dummy" type="button" style="display: none" runat="server" />
            <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" 
                    ID="mpeThePopup" 
                    TargetControlID="dummy" 
                    PopupControlID="pnlModalPopUpPanel" /> 
             <asp:Panel ID="pnlModalPopUpPanel" runat="server" style="border: 2px solid black; position:absolute; width:600px; height: 520px; display:none">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpInnerUpdatePanel" runat="Server" UpdateMode="Conditional"> 
                    <ContentTemplate> 
                        <p> 
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProducts" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>                                
                            &nbsp; 
                            <asp:Button ID="btnChooseProduct" runat="server" Text="Choose" onclick="btnChooseProduct_Click"/> 
                            &nbsp; 
                            <asp:Button ID="btnCancelModalPopup" runat="server" Text="Cancel" /> 
                        </P> 
                        <div style="width: 200px; border: 1px solid red">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblText" Text="this is the label" ForeColor="Black" runat="server"></asp:Label><br /> 
                        </div>
                    </ContentTemplate>       
                    <Triggers> 
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnChooseProduct" EventName="Click" /> 
                    </Triggers> 
                </asp:UpdatePanel> 
             </asp:Panel> 
        </ContentTemplate> 
    </asp:UpdatePanel> 
</div> 
</form>
```

codebehind:

```
protected void btnChooseProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblText.Text = "You have selected " + ddlProducts.SelectedItem.Text;
    //Show ModalPopup 
    mpeThePopup.Show(); 
}

protected void lbtnRed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddlProducts.Items.Clear();

    //Populate DropDownList Items 
    ddlProducts.Items.Add(new ListItem("Red Balloon", "Red Balloon"));
    ddlProducts.Items.Add(new ListItem("Red Apple", "Red Apple"));
    ddlProducts.Items.Add(new ListItem("Red Shirt", "Red Shirt"));
    ddlProducts.Items.Add(new ListItem("Red Watch", "Red Watch"));
    mpeThePopup.Show();

}
```

Comment: I make a test and its work to me, so you have some javascript bug that you can find as: Open your browser console and see for errors. Other way, remove temporary yours UpdatePanels to see actually what is the error...

Comment: Did you use the exact code that I posted? Because I just tried with Chrome & IE11, and `lblText` doesn't change after clicking on `btnChooseProduct`.

Comment: yes I use that code, of cource as it is miss some javascript, how ever I make it work. Do what I say you, open the console, see for errors.

Comment: You were right. The console was showing error `AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts`. I checked and I had version 3.5. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was referencing AJAX Control Toolkit 3.5 in VS 2010. I just deleted that reference, downloaded and installed AjaxControlToolkit.dll 4.0, and everything's working now.

Thanks.